# Set custom user-agent for Firefox - selenium-standalone / webdriverjsAngular

Tags: node.js, firefox, selenium, webdriver-io

I'm using selenium-standalone with [webdriverio](http://webdriver.io/) and i'm trying to set a custom user-agent.

```
var selenium = require('selenium-standalone');
var webdriverjsAngular = require('webdriverjs-angular');
var FirefoxProfile = require('firefox-profile');
var myProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
myProfile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "custom-user-agent");


var webDriverOptions = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        firefox_profile: myProfile
    }
};
var seleniumOptions = {
    drivers: {
        chrome: {
            version: '2.9',
            arch: process.arch,
            baseURL: 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'
        },
    },
};

selenium.start(seleniumOptions, function(err, child) {
    webdriverjsAngular.remote(webDriverOptions)
     .....
}
```

The code is working, except the settings for `firefox-profile` are not used, and Firefox is still using this user-agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0`.

How can i set a custom user-agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the last part:

```
var myProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
myProfile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "custom-user-agent");    

myProfile.encoded(function (encodedProfile) {
    // output the generated encoded profile as stdout
    // NOTE: if an error occurs with the encodedProfile then the default Firefox settings will be used in your tests    
  var webDriverOptions = {
      desiredCapabilities: {
          browserName: 'firefox',
          firefox_profile: encodedProfile
      }
  };
});
```